# How to perform OCR on an image containing euro symbol with Tess4J?

Tags: java, ocr, tesseract, tess4j

I have the following image I want to OCR:

[image]

I'm using [Tess4J](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/) for this and followed [these instructions](http://tess4j.sourceforge.net/codesample.html).

This is what I'm trying:

```
import java.io.File;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.ITesseract;
import net.sourceforge.tess4j.TesseractException;


public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//        Perform OCR
//        ===========
        File imageFile = new File("./CroppedSubtotal.png");
        ITesseract instance = new Tesseract();  // JNA Interface Mapping

        try {
            String result = instance.doOCR(imageFile);
            System.out.println("====== Result: " + result);
        } catch (TesseractException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this in IntelliJ the console returns the following:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk ...
====== Result: 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

What can I try to fix this?

Update:

When I OCR on the images below it does work

[image: text]
[image: numbers without euro symbol]

The euro symbol must be the cause. I've tried adding it to the whitelist but without success

```
instance.setTessVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "€0123456789,.");
```

Comment: And when you run it from the command line? Also: add a breakpoint on the line where you print the result and inspect the contents of the `result` variable.

Answer (score 0):

Tesseract recognizes Euro sign just fine using English data pack. Your console may have not been able to display it.